# Template type paremeter not expanding as desired

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, c++20

I was experimenting on `c++` TMP when I noticed how powerful templates can be.
But at some point I wondered why is the following code invalid yet it uses variadic template type expansion(1). When non-type variadic expansion works fine(2). The diviation doesn't make sense as in both the expanded parameters will not be usable. Or is it a problem with my compiler. `clang++ std=c++20`

*Tests*

```cpp
template<typename Y> struct Exp{
    static const bool useless=false;
};
template<typename... T> auto initAll1(int forAll,T...ts){
    std::array a={(ts,forAll)...};
}
template<typename... T> auto initAll2(int forAll){
    std::array a={(T,forAll)...};
}
template<typename... T> auto initAll3(int forAll){
    std::array a={(Exp<T>::useless,forAll)...};
    return a;
}
```

I am talking about `initAll2`. It is not working, I made `initAll3` to avoid the error.

Comment: You're expanding into an initializer list for `std::array`. `(T, forAll)` is an expression (`,` is an operator which always returns the right hand side). So, you're dropping a type name into an expression, which doesn't make sense. Did you  mean to use `T{}` and fill it with the default values of those types?

Comment: @parktomatomi - IMHO, you should expand the comment in an answer (but regarding the `T{}`... what about if `T` isn't default constructible? the use if `Exp<T>::useless` (but maybe simply `Exp<T>{}` without a `useless` inside it) is a way to avoid the problem)

Comment: @max66 Exactly. But in both cases there is a cost of constructing useless object. It would be easier if ```std::array a={(T,forAll)...};``` worked.

Comment: @D.Sikilai - Given the optimizations of modern compilers, I don't think there is a real cost for a discarded `Exp<T>{}` object (maybe `Exp` can be reduced as `template <typename> struct Exp {};`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As max66's comment said, option 3 likely won't have any runtime overhead. But you could do this if you wanted something cleaner:

```cpp
template<typename... T>
auto initAll2(int forAll){
    std::array a={std::conditional_t<true, int, T>{ forAll }...};
}
```

Comment: Nice idea the use of `std::conditional_t`; anyway, the question is regarding why is not working `(T, forAll)...`; I think you should transcribe and expand, from your comment in your answer, the part regarding the comma operator.